# Fetch Table Column values into varchar in SQL Sever

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have

```
tableA (strX varchar(10), strY varchar(10))
Values ('Me', 'Today')
       ('You', 'Yesterday')

tableB (strP varchar(10), strQ varchar(10))
Values ('He', 'Rejected')
       ('Me', 'Accepted')
       ('You', 'Rejected')
       ('Her', 'Accepted')
```

and my Query in stored procedure goes like below and is being called more than 10 times in my procedure.

```
Select * from tableB  Where strp in (Select strX from tableA);
```

Is there a way I can store Select strX from tableA into a variable and make use of it like below ?

```
Declare @strValues = (Select strX from tableA);

Select * from tableB  Where strp in @strValues;
```

no of entries for `strX` is dynamic in `tableA`.

Comment: what do you mean it's being called many times? Sample data and expected output would be helpful here.

Comment: Why would you want to? If you think it'll be faster somehow (because you've "calculated it once and stored it in a variable") -- it might very well not be. The `IN` can produce a `JOIN` with indexes; if you hard-coded a list of values (through dynamic SQL) you could end up with a gigantic branch of `OR` clauses that might, in bad cases, actualy be slower. T-SQL is not a classical imperative language.

Comment: Question updated !! I know I can use a inner join but looking for alternatives.

Comment: Why would you want an alternative to a join, especially for something this simple? I think you have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: tableB has 5k rows where tableA could potentially have 2 to 3 rows. Performance is bad when I use inner join.

Comment: The performance isn't because of the query... post your DDL and Indexes... and while you're at it, paste the actual execution plan here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: JOINs are designed to for this purpose. Wonder what could be faster than that?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you bother trying to convert a working query to something else?

If performance is your concern, then simply make `strX` the primary key:

```
create tableA (
    strX varchar(10) primary key,
    strY varchar(10)
);
```

This should be pretty wickedly fast.

Comment: @Sailor . . . It is counterintuitive that changing the referenced column to a primary key would make it worse   How unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Not to detract from what the rest are saying here, but I think a table variable like below is technically what you're asking for:

```
declare @strValues table (value varchar(10))
insert into @strValues 
    select strx from tableA

select * from tableB where strP in (select * from @strValues)
```

I doubt this would be an improvement but present it for what it's worth.